# How to setup JavaPOS on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, jpos

I am attempting to setup JavaPOS on a Linux machine and am not having any success.  I have installed:

```
rxtx
  *.so -> JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64
  *.jar -> JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext
com api
  comm.jar -> JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext
  javax.comm.properties JAVA_HOME/lib
```

When I attempt to load the device, I am getting a JPos Exception "Service does not exist".

Comment: are you succeeded with your problem, because i'm having the same problem, will you be able to assist me.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the jpos.xml file is not being loaded.

Try loading the file manually using the code below:

```
System.setProperty("jpos.config.populatorFile", path_to_jpos_xml);
System.setProperty("jpos.loader.serviceManagerClass","jpos.loader.simple.SimpleServiceManager");
System.setProperty("jpos.config.regPopulatorClass", "jpos.config.simple.xml.XercesRegPopulator");

JposServiceManager manager = JposServiceLoader.getManager();
manager.getEntryRegistry().load();
```

Comment: I am no longer working with POS so I won't be able to test this.