# How to Create jpos.xml file

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, printing, javapos

First of all thank you for taking time to help me. 
i have experience with Epson pos Adk and i know how to use it, but now i'm trying to connect to pos printer without using a vendor modified jpos libs.
i want to use pure javaPos to connect to printer, so i have two questions at the moment

1. I don't know how to create jpos.xml for a printer
2. I'm working on Ubuntu environment so need to know how to properly install jpos, i fount this [installing jpos in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064814/how-to-setup-javapos-on-linux) but i can't test this because i don't have a printer right now so is there any other installations or configurations i need to do for ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Vendors of hardware provide examples for using their devices via javapos
For example you can visit sites Starmicronics for getting samples jpos.xml for their thermal printers or datalogic for getting samples jpos.xml for their barcode-scanners